# Django REST update foreign key by id

Tags: django-rest-framework

Problem:

I want to update a foreign key field and I can not find my mistake why my changes to that fields are not saved. I want to be able to update `clan` and `wingman`.

**serializer.py**

```
class UpdateProfileInfoSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.CharField(required=True)

    wingmanId = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    clanId = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    image = serializers.ImageField(required=False)
    titleImage = serializers.ImageField(required=False)
    description = serializers.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = ProfileInfo
        fields = ['id', 'clanId', 'description', 'image', 'titleImage', 'wingmanId']

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        clan_id = validated_data.get('clanId')
        wingman_id = validated_data.get('wingmanId')

        if clan_id:
            if instance.clan:
                instance.clan.id = clan_id

        if wingman_id:
            if instance.wingman:
                instance.wingman.id = wingman_id

        instance.image = validated_data.get('image', instance.image)
        instance.titleImage = validated_data.get('titleImage', instance.titleImage)
        instance.description = validated_data.get('description', instance.description)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Thank you for your help. I think I am doing something fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this please, I think it is better.

```
class UpdateProfileInfoSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.CharField(required=True)

    wingmanId = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    clanId = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    image = serializers.ImageField(required=False)
    titleImage = serializers.ImageField(required=False)
    description = serializers.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = ProfileInfo
        fields = ['id', 'clanId', 'description', 'image', 'titleImage', 'wingmanId']

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        clan_id = validated_data.get('clanId')
        wingman_id = validated_data.get('wingmanId')

        if clan_id:
            if instance.clan:
                try:
                    clan_obj = Clan.objects.get(id=clan_id)
                    instance.clan = clan_obj
                except:
                    pass

        if wingman_id:
            if instance.wingman:
                try:
                    wingman_obj = Wingman.objects.get(id=wingman_id) 
                    instance.wingman = wingman_obj
                except:
                    pass

        instance.image = validated_data.get('image', instance.image)
        instance.titleImage = validated_data.get('titleImage', instance.titleImage)
        instance.description = validated_data.get('description', instance.description)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```